# Implementing Java code from Eclipse to Jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

I know this is a very basic question to ask. But i am facing a challenge in implementing my working java code from Eclipse onto Jmeter. I am not sure on how to do it. Would be great if anyone can throw light on this.

Answer (score 0):

1. If your code relies on any dependencies/external libraries which are not in JMeter already - make sure to copy them to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. In JMeter add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to your Test Plan and make sure that `groovy` is chosen in the language dropdown
3. Copy your code from Eclipse to JSR223 Sampler
4. Run your code
5. If the code isn't doing what it is supposed to be doing check jmeter.log file for any suspicious entries
6. Fix the errors according to what you're seeing
7. Repeat steps 4-6 until it's working

Also you can package your Java code as .jar file, copy the .jar to JMeter Classpath and access the class/method from the JSR223 Sampler. More information: [How to Reuse Your JMeter Code with JAR Files and Save Time](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-reuse-your-jmeter-code-with-jar-files-and-save-time)